# Use Schematron to check that every element of reference XML is defined in target XML document

Tags: xml, schematron

I want to use Schematron to validate an XML document by checking that it contains all required elements from a **separate reference XML source**. For example, I have an XML file `requiredIngredients.xml` that defines:

```
<requiredIngredients>
   <ingredient>Water</ingredient>
   <ingredient>Flour</ingredient>
   <ingredient>Salt</ingredient>
</requiredIngredients>
```

Using this I want to validate another XML file with content such as:

```
<myRecipe>
   <ingredient>Sugar</ingredient>
   <ingredient>Water</ingredient>
</myRecipe>
```

In this case, I would want two separate errors, one stating that "Flour" is missing and the other one that "Salt" is missing. Using Schematron if I go for something like ...

```
<rule context="/myRecipe">...</rule>
```

... I can test against the `requiredIngredients.xml` file using the `document` function (e.g. with a `every .. in .. satisfies` check) but this would only produce a single error. I could achieve this by translating my `requiredIngredients.xml` itself into a set of Schematron assertions but would really like to **keep this separate** as there can be numerous such files (consider this as an input to my validation rules alongside the actual XML to validate).

Any ideas would be very welcome!

Comment: I don't see any satisfying solution. Any rule need a context and in your case only the root element makes sense. But any assert or report can produce only one error. If you would validate the `requiredIngredients.xml` you could set the context on ingredient elements and test if it was used, but this is not useful for you, is it? Maybe the `pattern/@document` attribute of Schematron 2016 would help you? Didn't worked with it til now. But it shall switch into other documents. Maybe you can combine it with `@subject`?

Comment: Thanks @NicoKutscherauer. I thought of the pattern/@document approach but it didn't see exactly how to use it (also the validation library I'm using doesn't support it yet). For now I'm doing the validation in two steps: (1) preprocess the ```requiredIngredients.xml``` with XSLT to produce a Schematron file based on its contents, (2) validate the input. This Schematron has the root element as context (as you well pointed out) and applies the rules giving me the results I expect. Not perfect but works. Will wait in case of other ideas and then post an answer with my workaround. Thanks!